# Constrain Int variable to not be 0 in swift

Tags: swift

Is there any provision in Swift to declare an Int variable and constrain it to a min value? E.g. no less than 10?  I am aware of Closed and Open Ranges, but I'm not sure how I can convert that to an int. I've also tried using where syntax without luck Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a property wrapper for this, here is an example with a dynamic limit

```
@propertyWrapper struct LimitedInt {
    let limit: Int
    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { internalValue }
        set { internalValue = newValue < limit ? limit : newValue }
    }
    private var internalValue: Int

    init(wrappedValue internalValue: Int, limit: Int) {
        self.limit = limit
        self.internalValue = internalValue < limit ? limit : internalValue
    }
}
```

and it's used when declaring a property like this

```
@LimitedInt(limit: 10) var first = 12
```

---

To make it a little more advanced we could make our property wrapper generic

```
@propertyWrapper struct Limited<Value: Comparable>
```

so it could be used with other types than `Int`. But to make it even more useful we could make it possible to supply the logic for checking the value and correcting it so here is a more versatile version

```
@propertyWrapper struct Limited<Value> {
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { internalValue }
        set { internalValue = validation(newValue) }
    }
    private var internalValue: Value
    private let validation: (Value) -> Value

    init(wrappedValue internalValue: Value, validation: @escaping (Value) -> Value ) {
        self.internalValue = validation(internalValue)
        self.validation = validation
    }
}
```

Our previous example then becomes

```
@Limited<Int>(validation: { $0 >= 10 ? $0 : 10 }) var first = 12
```

But we could of course do whatever we want

```
@Limited<String>(validation: { Calendar.current.isDateInWeekend(.now) ? "Party!!!" : $0.capitalized }) var second = "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it inside `didSet`

```
var n : Int = 10 {
    didSet {
        if n < 10{
            print("not ok")
            n = oldValue
        }
    }
}
```